# NgModel not found while create directive

Tags: angularjs

Here is my directive fileUpload for validation of image extenstion. I am not getting what is missing here. (Missing Required Controller Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'fileUpload', can't be found! ) Please if any one can look in to this.

I found so many reference to the same question but no luck . please dont mark this as repeat question.

```
      App.directive('fileUpload', function () {
            return {
                scope: true,        //create a new scope
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, el, attrs,ctrl) {
                    ctrl.$validators.images = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                        console.log(modelValue);
                        console.log(viewValue);

                      };
                    ngModel.$setValidity('extension', true);
                    el.bind('change', function (event) {
                        var files = event.target.files;
                        var validFormats = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
                        var validSize = 500000;
                        for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
                            var ext = files[i].name.split('.');
                            var size = files[i].size;
                            if (ext !== undefined) {
                                var isExist = validFormats.indexOf(ext[1].toLowerCase()) >= 0 ? 1 : 0;
                                if (isExist == true && validSize >= (size)) {
                                    ngModel.$setValidity('extension', true);
                                } else {
                                    ngModel.$setValidity('extension', false);
                                }
                            }
                            //emit event upward
                            scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
                        }                                       
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Input :

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback" style="margin-left: 10px;">
     <input   name="file" type="file"  ng-model="images" accept="image/*"  multiple="true" file-upload  />
      <div style="color:grey; font-size: 12px;">
           Extensions : jpg , jpeg , png , gif<br>
           Size : 500KB 
      </div>
      <div ng-messages="frmSupportPanelist.file.$error" ng-if="frmSupportPanelist.file.$touched">
       <label id="message-required-error" class="validation-error-label" for="file" ng-message="extension">Please select valid Image </label>
       </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `function (scope, el, attrs,ngModel)`

Comment: As Maher said, you are accessing it wrong.. fourth argument is itself `ngModel` in this case

Comment: Thanks Maher, I have changed that parameter still showing the same error